# Magento : Hide attribute variation in listing

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

Here's my problem :
i'm having 2 shirts with colors Red & Blue each with sizes S,M,L
(6 products) those 6 products are associated with Real-Madrid shirt

i need to list only 2 shirts red and blue (size does not matter)

i tried to override

> _getLoadedProductsCollection() in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
>    but it did n't work for me

i must have only 1 configurable product for those 6 shirts So sadly i cant use 2 configurable products for each color

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as following :

1- override prepareProductCollection($collection) in  Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer

2- after preparing list of products u need to be shown

3- use $collection -> addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',$ids

> $collection
> ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')-> getProductAttributes())
>
> ->addMinimalPrice()
>
> ->addFinalPrice()
>
> ->addTaxPercents()
>
> ->addUrlRewrite($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId())
>
> // filter your products here
>
> ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $ids);

)